# Writing and reading to a mysql table an array data structure with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am build a data structure using multidimensional associative arrays.  Can I update that data structure into a mysql table field and then read it back again?

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
$result = mysql_query("select * FROM color") or die(mysql_error());
$colors = "";
while($colorrec = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 $colors[$colorrec['ID']][0] = $colorrec['Description'];
 $colors[$colorrec['ID']][1] = $colorrec['HexCode'];
}
```

If I now do:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE tempfile SET ColorInfo = '".$colors."' WHERE ID = '".tempID."'");
```

Can I then do:

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from tempfile WHERE ID = '".tempID."'");
$temprec = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$colors = $temprec['ColorInfo'];
```

Comment: what are you having problems with? What errors are you getting with the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [serialize](http://us.php.net/serialize) it to hold it's data type, then [unserialize](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it when you fetch it back.

```
$result = mysql_query("select * FROM color") or die(mysql_error());
$colors = array();
while($colorrec = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $colors[$colorrec['ID']] = array($colorrec['Description'], $colorrec['HexCode']);
}

mysql_query("UPDATE tempfile SET ColorInfo = '".serialize($colors)."' WHERE ID = '".$tempID."'");

$result = mysql_query("select * from tempfile WHERE ID = '".$tempID."'");
$temprec = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$colors = unserialize($temprec['ColorInfo']);
```

Comment: Cool. I did not think what I was trying to do would work, but I was sure there was a way to do it.  I will give it a try.